# Hex to Binary String Java

Tags: java, encryption, binary, hex

I'm making Encryption now, and on the step 7 which i need to make the HEX String Array(which I have transferred from ASCII into a String Array) into Binary String.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  { 
System.out.println("HEX to Binary: ");
String[] stringHextoBinary = new String[HS.length]; //HS is the String Array for Hex           numbers that i save from last step

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int l = 0;
for(String s : HS) {
    builder.append(s);
    if (s.length()<=1){
       stringHextoBinary[l] = HexToBinary(s.charAt(0));
         l++;
   System.out.print(HexToBinary(s.charAt(0)) + ",");

 }else{
    stringHextoBinary[l] = HexToBinary(s.charAt(0))+HexToBinary(s.charAt(1));
        l++;
                   System.out.print(HexToBinary(s.charAt(0))+HexToBinary(s.charAt(1))+",");
 }              

 public static String HexToBinary(char Hex) {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(Hex), 16);
            String Bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
            return Bin;
      }                 
 }
```

the if statement can be work with HEX when it has one digit or two digits.
But my problem is here that it prints out 
HEX to Binary: 
11100,111,111,10111,11101,
its losing 0 in it. :(

so that when i encrypt word "apple" , and decrypt it with same code will come back with word "pppxl" :(

Hope I can get answer ASAP and thanks a lot!

Comment: the Hex String Array is "34 7 7 b1 35"

Comment: I tried with some web tool which transfer Hex to Binary should get result with "00110100 01110111 10110001 00110101"

Comment: Added some code to my answer to properly pad the binary string, borrowing off of what David said.

Comment: Scrapped David's code and added some of my own.  If you want to try it, I believe it'll work for your purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your method taking in chars, you can simply have it take in a string and convert it to binary using:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  { 
System.out.println("HEX to Binary: ");
String[] stringHextoBinary = new String[HS.length]; //HS is the String Array for Hex           numbers that i save from last step

// creates the string builder, count, and declaration
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
int l = 0;
string binaryDigits;

// iterates through string array and appends to string that's being built
// (for whatever reason)
for(String s : HS) {
    builder.append(s);
    binaryDigits = HexToBinary(s);
    stringHextoBinary[l++] = binaryDigits;
    System.out.print(binaryDigits);
}

// transforms hex string to binary string without losing 0's
public static String HexToBinary(String Hex) {
    string toReturn = new BigInteger(Hex, 16).toString(2);
    return String.format("%" + (Hex.length*4) + "s", toReturn).replace(' ', '0')
}
```

You don't need to combine code, as this is all the code that you need to convert a string to  a binary string separated by spaces.  It will iterate through and change every string to a binary string.

Comment: @Downvoter, any explanation as to the downvote?  Not sure what my answer lacks in regards to the question.

Comment: Using BigInteger to convert to hex will let you loose the initial bits set to zero. Note that I did not downvote (yet).

Comment: Edited to not lose zero bits

Comment: sorry couldn't combine you guys' code :(  and i have one more method over it which transferred orginal word to Hex with String[], so the  method can't be HexToBinary(String Hex). and since i m combining those method (word to birnay --> binary to Hex--> hex to string) in Main, so i dont actually understand where to add your code :P can you plz explain more ?

Comment: Added some comments.  Essentially this is all the code you'll need to transform from string to binary string.

Comment: sorry that i'm asking so much , but the vailble s is in main which can't be used in the public static String HexToBinary(String Hex), what can i change to? also the BigInteger(Hex, 16) doesn't work, but i have imported BigInteger :(

Comment: Yeah, sorry, instead of 's' that should be 'Hex', and the BigInteger should be 'new BigInteger.'  Edited code to reflect that.

Comment: thanks :) its without error now , but print out for 110100 111 11110110001  110101   10010

Comment: I was missing a parenthetical.  Change the return statement to
return String.format("%" + (Hex.length*4) + "s", toReturn).replace(' ', '0')

Comment: it work with this "return String.format("%" + (Hex.length()*4) + "s", toReturn.replace(' ', '0'));"   but still losing 0 in front of "110100 111 11110110001 110101 10010" which should be like 0000111

Comment: What that line of code is supposed to do is it's supposed to make the string a certain length that the "Format" function fills with whitespace, and then call .replace() on the string to replace the whitespace with 0's.  If the parenthetical is on the outside, then it will try to replace whitespace that is not there yet.  Try changing the position of the parentheses to where I specified.

Comment: thanks for your help :) its a part of the whole stuff I'm working hard on during these days :) but my group members didn't take anything which they think its useless :( so hard of life..

Answer (score 1):

Use this method of the Apache commons `StringUtils` class

```
public String leftPad(String str, int size, char padding);
```

after you've converted your number to 0s and 1s.  It might look like

```
String paddedBin = StringUtils.leftPad(bin, 8, '0');
```

for example.  Not sure how many digits you actually want to pad it to.

Comment: sorry couldn't combine you guys' code :(  and i have one more method over it which transferred orginal word to Hex with String[], so the  method can't be HexToBinary(String Hex). and since i m combining those method (word to birnay --> binary to Hex--> hex to string) in Main, so i dont actually understand where to add your code :P can you plz explain more ?

Comment: Don't combine this with any other answer.  I wrote this answer to stand alone, not as a "mixer".  Just take your original code, and add the one line of my answer in at the end of your `HexToBinary` method.  Then instead of returning `bin`, return `paddedBin` instead.

Comment: Did you download the Apache commons library and add it to your project?

Comment: no.. which one should i done load? and is it to put in my library?

Comment: Umm, yes.  Just get the latest version of Apache commons.  Add the JAR file to some place that your project will see it - probably you have a directory called "lib", or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method implementation:

```
public static String hexCharToBinary(char c) {
    final int v;
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        v = c - '0';
    } else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') {
        v = 10 + c - 'A';
    } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') {
        v = 10 + c - 'a';
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return String.format("%4s", Integer.toBinaryString(v & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
}
```

Comment: Note that you should prefer converting from hexadecimals to bytes first, then converting the bytes to binary *encoding* for viewing.

Answer (score -2):

Try this out:

```
stringHextoBinary[l] = new BigInteger(s,16).toString(2);
```

What this is doing is creating a new Integer with radix of 16 for you hex numbers and then converting that to a string of base 2 (binary). Haven't tested this out since I am not near a computer with a jvm installed but this is just an idea since you seem to need ideas in a hurry.

This should work too:

```
stringHextoBinary[l] = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(s, 16));
```

Comment: sorry :( it doesn't work with it, but thanks that you reply so fast :)